# Syncing 1TB+ to a iSCSI device, software needed

Tags: rsync, copy, synchronization

I need to sync a local disk to a iSCSI mount on Windows (server 2003), and I'm struggling to find software that's capable of doing so in a reasonable timeframe.

Notes on the current 1TB disk:
- 800GB currently in use
- Contains a folder with several hundred thousand subfolders, which in turn have several thousand files, ...

So I'm trying to find a piece of software that can handle such large filelists, and give me a good timeframe on when this will be copied. I've tried DeltaCopy (the rSync GUI client for Windows), but it's intolerably slow and doesn't provide me with a good estimate time remaining.

DeltaCopy: http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp

Does anyone know alternative software for Windows, that would do this well?

Answer (score 1):

Robocopy is the classic tool for this.

It won't however give you a good estimate of time remaining, and this is going to be quite slow. You should however be able to get a reasonable idea by looking at the number of files and amount of free space on the iSCSI volume periodically and extrapolate.

You may gain a little performance by disabling the NTFS last access time stamping.

If it's 2003 Server 32 bit, I'd also not be surprised if you bump in to unpaged pool depletion issues during the copy (You're copying hundreds of millions of files.)

Comment: Too bad it's not a 2008 server. If it were, there is an /MT switch which allows ROBOCOPY to copy in a multi-threaded fashion. This is typically much faster, even on local filesystems, as it allows metadata and data copy operations to be pipelined and parallelized. Any chance of moving the source disk(s) to a 2008 box? Or perhaps temporarily booting from a 2008 install on a different hard disk?

Answer (score 0):

RichCopy can help...Robocopy has a lot of adjustable values.  Most important are probably to keep retry timeouts and number of retries to a minimum.  Most of the time Robocopy will be probably waiting on the underlying disk/filesystem metadata operations to complete.  Any tool/filesystem would have trouble with that...